# How can I use a SHA to schedule AWS EventBridge task using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a lambda that runs every morning at 8:00am EST. This lambda sends error notifications to a Slack channel. The problem is that this particular lambda is created and run simultaneously by several tenanted environments, so the alerts produced by the lambda overlap each other in the slack channel. I want to hash the tenant name and produce an integer between 1 and 60 that will stagger the deployment of the lambda over the course of the hour. Currently, the terraform governing the lambda's timing looks like:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "notifications" {
  name = "${var.tenant}-check-for-errors"
  description = "Send notifications to slack"

  schedule_expression = "cron(0 12 ? * MON-FRI *)"
```

I want `schedule_expression` to be something like `cron(${parseint(sha1(var.tenant), 16)/60} 12 ? * MON-FRI *)` so each value of var.tenant will be different.

Can I do this, and what would it look like?

Comment: What is the business point of this? Aren't you just delaying error notifications from being sent?

Comment: Error messages are only sent once a day to begin with. The point is to centralize the errors so we have one location to view all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my code works exactly as written, but AWS was down.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "notifications" {
  name        = "${var.tenant}-check-logs-for-errors"
  description = "Send notifications to slack for errors found in logs every weekday"

  schedule_expression = "cron(${parseint(sha1(var.tenant), 16)%60} 12 ? * MON-FRI *)"
}
```

`$parseint(sha1(var.tenant), 16)%60` works perfectly as written.